# DatePart with Weekday having in Clause in it

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How does this below Statement working internally ?

```
DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CAL.DAY) in (1,7) then 0
```

I tried running this but gives me error, if i remove the in clause then it works fine.

This is the complete code:

```
SELECT CAL.DAY AS DATE
    ,FISCAL_PERIOD DATEPART(year, CAL.DAY)
    ,CASE 
        WHEN DATEPART(month, CAL.DAY) = 1
            AND DATEPART(day, CAL.DAY) = 1
            THEN 0
        WHEN DATEPART(month, CAL.DAY) = 1
            AND DATEPART(day, CAL.DAY) = 2
            AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CAL.DAY) IN (
                1
                ,7
                )
            THEN 0
        WHEN DATEPART(month, CAL.DAY) = 1
            AND DATEPART(day, CAL.DAY) = 3
            AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CAL.DAY) IN (
                1
                ,7
                )
            THEN 0
        ELSE NULL
        END AS BUSINESS_DAY_OVERRIDE
    ,
INTO #Demo
FROM CAL
```

Comment: we need the rest of the code...on its own it doesn't make sense

Comment: select
  CAL.DAY as Date,
  FISCAL_PERIOD
  DATEPART(year, CAL.DAY),
  case
   when DATEPART(month, CAL.DAY) = 1 and DATEPART(day, CAL.DAY) = 1 then 0
   
   when DATEPART(month, CAL.DAY) = 1 and DATEPART(day, CAL.DAY) = 2 and DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CAL.DAY) in (1,7) then 0
   
   when DATEPART(month, CAL.DAY) = 1 and DATEPART(day, CAL.DAY) = 3 and DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CAL.DAY) in (1,7) then 0
   else null
  end as BUSINESS_DAY_OVERRIDE,
 INTO #Demo
 from  CAL

Answer (score 0):

[DATEPART(WEEKDAY, ...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql)  returns integers 1 to 7 representing the cycle of a week, there is nothing wrong with comparing that to IN(1,7)

There are syntax questions BEFORE you reach that case expression. If (for example) I assume there is a equal symbol following "FISCAL_PERIOD = " then the syntax is fine. (Or, perhaps that equal symbol should be a comma?)

```
SELECT cal.day AS [DATE], 
       FISCAL_PERIOD = Datepart(year, cal.day), 
       CASE 
         WHEN Datepart(month, cal.day) = 1 
              AND Datepart(day, cal.day) = 1 THEN 0 
         WHEN Datepart(month, cal.day) = 1 
              AND Datepart(day, cal.day) = 2 
              AND Datepart(weekday, cal.day) IN ( 1, 7 ) THEN 0 
         WHEN Datepart(month, cal.day) = 1 
              AND Datepart(day, cal.day) = 3 
              AND Datepart(weekday, cal.day) IN ( 1, 7 ) THEN 0 
         ELSE NULL 
       END     AS BUSINESS_DAY_OVERRIDE 
FROM   cal
```

Be careful using "date" as a column name, it is also a TSQL keyword. Personally I don't recommend using it as a column name.